# Building iOS Apps with only development certificates [Intel XDK]

Tags: ios, iphone, intel-xdk

I´m trying to build an iOS Application in order to test it in my iPhone. But I have a problem, I only have a student developer account associated with my university, so I only have access to Development certificates.

Is it posible build an app with the Intel XDK environment having only development certificates? I´m not going to upload the application to the App Store and I don´t need it. I only want to install the application on my device.

Answer (score 0):

That should work just fine. If you can:

- Create an app ID
- Use IntelXDK's generated .csr (Certificate Signing Request) to create a .cer (certificate)
- Create a provisioning profile

Then you should be able to do everything short of releasing to the app store. You will just need to make sure your provisioning profile includes the Unique ID of your testing device. For a rough idea of how to work through this process, I recommend checking out this guide: [Uploading iOS App to App Store with IntelXDK](https://www.scirra.com/forum/tutorial-upload-your-ios-game-to-app-store-using-intel-xdk_t148447)

I know it's title implies "App Store", but steps for deploying to a single/multiple devices for testing are also included. If you have any questions, let me know!

Comment: This is the answer Intel gave me: "BTW, in a future release we are adding the ability to manage multiple certs (debug and develop), so the feature you are looking for will be added, but is not available with our current build system. Today, if you try to upload a dev cert the build system will refuse to use it."

Comment: Hmm. Good to know. It may be worth creating your own answer and accepting it. Thanks for following up!